# Spring 4 CachingConnectionFactory with JMS 2.0 doesn't properly cache Producers

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

We just upgraded to Spring 4 and JMS 2.0.  We are using a `CachingConnectionFactory` and a `JmsTemplate` to publish messages and noticed that when publishing to a destination, the first attempt works and then further attempts to publish to the same destination cause the following exception:

> Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The producer is closed

Everything worked fine with Spring 3.2 and JMS 1.1 so I did some digging to see what the problem was and it seems the issue is in the `CachedMessageProducer` class.  Normally this class re-implements all of the methods in the `MessageProducer` interface.  Specifically there is a `close()` method that is re-implemented and will only reset properties but keep the producer alive (since it is a caching factory) after a message is sent using the `JmsTemplate`.

However, there is a new method in Spring 4 called `getProxyIfNecessary` that determines whether or not JMS 2.0 is being used and when it detects JMS 2.0 it creates a `Jms2MessageProducerInvocationHandler` proxy.  The invoke method of this proxy is delegating all calls to the original `MessageProducer` object, and seems to be bypassing method calls in the CachedMessageProducer.  The end result is that the close method gets called on the original `MessageProducer` object (which we don't want since it should be cached).  This means that future attempts to publish give the exception that the producer has been closed.

Has anyone else had this issue before?  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug with the new JMS 2.0 support in Spring.

Comment: I am assuming that this is a bug and I created a Jira ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11949

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you found out yourself, this is indeed a bug and this is resolved in the upcoming `4.0.6` and `4.1.RC1`. Thanks!